# EF: saveChanges succeed, but changes reflect in DB only when edditing existing reference member

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I'm using EF.

I have a `Parent` entity named `MamConfiguration_V1`

it has a EntityCollection of `MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1`

my context is `mMaMDBEntities`.

I'm trying to add a new `MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1` to an existing `MamConfiguration_V1`

I get no errors, but no record is added to the DB.

When I update an existing reference member, changes are reflected in the DB.

What am I doing wrong?

public MamConfiguration_V1 Save(MamConfiguration_V1 item)
        {

```
        try
        {

            var itemFromDB = mMaMDBEntities.MamConfiguration_V1.SingleOrDefault(a=> a.ConfigurationId == item.ConfigurationId);

            if (itemFromDB != null)
            {

                UpdateEfBrowsers(itemFromDB, item);

                mMaMDBEntities.SaveChanges();

                return item;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new KeyNotFoundException(string.Format("configurationId = {0} wasn't found in the DB", item.ConfigurationId));
            }

    }

    private void UpdateEfBrowsers(MamConfiguration_V1 itemFromDb, MamConfiguration_V1 itemFromUi)
    {
        foreach (var item in itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.ToList())
        {
            if (itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.All(b => b.BrowserVersionId != item.BrowserVersionId))
            {
                mMaMDBEntities.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.DeleteObject(item);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Count; i++)
        {
            var element = itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.ElementAt(i);

            var item =
                itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.SingleOrDefault(b => b.BrowserVersionId == element.BrowserVersionId);

            if (item != null)
            {
                // copy properties from element to item
            }

                //add new
            else
            {
                //element.Browser = mMaMDBEntities.Browsers.Single(browserItem =>
                //                                                 browserItem.BrowserID == element.BrowserID);

                //element.MamConfigurationId = itemFromDb.ConfigurationId;

                element.MamConfiguration_V1 = null;

                mMaMDBEntities.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.AddObject(element);

                itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Add(element);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Count; i++)
        {


...

                mMaMDBEntities.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.AddObject(element);

                itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Add(element);
}
```

The problem was that the `AddObject` or `Add`

remove an item from itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Count

and thus decreases count.

I don't know why.

I have replaced with `foreach`

Answer (score -1):

You need to write

```
*databasename*.SaveChanges()
```

After you have added to the database. Otherwise it will not save it